# UserControl instead of DataTemplates - is there a way for big collections?

Tags: windows-phone-7, collections, user-controls, datatemplate

There are two ways. May be both are stupid...
I have to display some collections of items.

**First one.**

I use DataTemplate for ListBoxItem.
Just set itemSource = myCollection;

That's all.  Simple scheme.

**Second one.**

**Each item** in my collection has property **view**. It's a UserControl. That define how item renders.

Create **DataTemplate** with **ContentPresenter** only.

Binding **Content** property to a **view**.

Just set itemSource = myCollection;

That's all. More complex. But works too.

Has second one right to live? My doubt is that I have to create instance of UserControl for every item in my collection?

Is not it too expensive for collection with over than 500 items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is much difference, with the DataTemplate approach the framework will create an instance of the DataTemplate for each item in the collection. In the second approach an instance of the user control will be created for each item, there may be a few more controls but only a few per item.

One reason the second approach could be preferable is that you can have logic around which content is bound. This could mean different user controls for each item in the list. Caliburn Micro lets you use this approach very naturally.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right - each element may has it's own view and logic. But for now I face some problem. How can I use any virtualization stuff with second approach?

Comment: I believe the list box itself will handle the virtualization, either approach will work with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the listbox won't auto page. There's another control to add that behaviour, when the name comes to me I'll edit this comment.

Comment: Sorry I meant that ListBox under the covers uses the VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: It wouldn't let me edit. But anyway... I was thinking of the DataPager but it appears there *is* virtualisation support in the WP7 listbox. However, some effort is required on your part. Here's a detailed walkthrough: http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Improving-ListBox-Performance-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7-Data-Virtualization.aspx

Comment: A further though: five hundred items in a listbox? Are you nuts? Build a little search page so users can type a fragment and pick from a much shorter list.

Comment: 2 Nigel Sampson, when I use second approach - built-in virtualization does not work. In my case - over 63 items will throw an error.

Comment: 2 Peter Wone, so you're wanna say, that second approach (dataTemplate with ContentPresenter only + UserControl view from ListBoxItem) will require some additional effort that describes in link you give?

Comment: 500 elements - just for a test.